# Ambiguity in delta equal sign

Tags: calculus, dirac-delta

I tried asking this yesterday but my wording was too bad. I will try again because it really confuses me.

Let's look at an identity like $$x^n\delta(x) = 0$$
Does the equality in this case mean it is right for every $x$ value? For $x\neq0$ it is trivial, but we can't plug in $x=0$.

What I see they do in textbooks is taking the integral of $x^n\delta(x)$ around $0$, and see it is indeed zero. **But why does that mean the expression itself is zero?**

I seem to be missing an important notion concerning delta "functions". Are they defined only under an integral in the singularity? I see nowhere such definition.

If I'm still unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Ask yourself what things integrate to $0$.  One answer is $0$ itself, but if you then consider $\int_{-\varepsilon}^{\varepsilon}f(x)$ you realise that symmetric functions also will.  But is $x^n\delta(x)$ symmetric *for all* $n$?

Comment: Do you mean odd functions? The identity is true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ if i'm not wrong, so it is also true for $x^3\delta(x)$. Can we again assume that means the expression is zero? I hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: Yes, sorry; I got asked a question while typing :)  Yes, basically you can eliminate every option except $0$ this way.  You can expand it to higher dimensions by noting that if you can find a line through the origin for which this argument works, it must extend to the whole space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)), like $\delta$, are defined as linear functionals over a space of smooth functions with compact support ($C_c^\infty$).

The action of a distribution $u$ on a test function $\varphi \in C_c^\infty$ is often denoted $\langle u, \varphi \rangle$ or with some abuse of notation, as an integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx.$

Multiplication of a distribution with a smooth function $f \in C^\infty$ is defined by
$$
\langle fu, \varphi \rangle = \langle u, f\varphi \rangle.
$$
In integral notation this is just the quite obvious
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (f(x)\,u(x)) \, \varphi(x) \, dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(x) \, (f(x)\,\varphi(x)) \, dx.
$$

The distribution $\delta$ is defined by $\langle \delta, \varphi \rangle = \varphi(0).$

By what I have now defined, we get
$$
\langle x^n \, \delta(x), \varphi(x) \rangle
= \langle \delta(x), x^n \, \varphi(x) \rangle
= (x^n\,\varphi(x))[x:=0]
= 0^n\,\varphi(0)
= 0.
$$
This is the quite exact meaning of $x^n\,\delta(x)=0.$

Comment: Thank you, but I think I don't quite get the last line. Why is it the exact meaning that expression being zero? I guess it is trivial and easy, I just fail to see how it follows so I will be glad if you pointed that out explicitly. I haven't seen this delta function formalism, since I'm a physics major, but I can follow your reasoning.

Comment: Two distributions $u$ and $v$ are equal if $\langle u, \varphi \rangle = \langle v, \varphi \rangle$ for all $\varphi \in C_c^\infty.$ Since the calculation shows that $\langle x^n \, \delta(x), \varphi(x) \rangle = \langle 0, \varphi(x) \rangle$ for every $\varphi$ we get $x^n \, \delta(x) = 0.$

Comment: By the way, the identity is of course valid for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ not for $n=0.$

Comment: Thank you, it is much clearer now!